# Does WCF Service work if User closes browser

Tags: c#, wcf

I am very new to WCF service, matter a fact I just started reading up about it yesterday, I have a web application that uploads large files to a server. I needed some type of worker that would upload those files asynchronously (on a worker thread), So I created a WCF service in my application. I would like to know if the user starts this task, and then closes the browser, will the service complete the task that was created. Everything worked fine when debugging but I want to make sure I am executing properly and making sure that it will complete even if the users exits there browser. Thanks for any help.

Implementation

```
var uploaderservice = new VideoUploader();
                    var tasks = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => uploaderservice.DoWork(stream, fileName, fileType, username, password, picasaalbumid, albumid));
```

Here is my WCF

```
 [OperationContract]
        public void DoWork(Stream stream,string fileName,string fileType,string username,string password,string picasaalbumid,string albumid)
        {
           //Will Do all the work 

        }
```

Comment: How is the client application implemented? As an ASP.NET website?

Comment: Yes asp.net application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the the file has been completely transmitted this will work as expected. However, if you close the browser during the transmission, the file transfer will be stopped.

The browser is responsible for sending the file and if it is closed, it cannot be sent.

Comment: Yes the file is already posted on a server and is timed to auto deleted after 45 min after it has been uploaded which is plenty of time to be able to upload the file.

Comment: @user516883 yes, the The task will run as expected if the browser has finished sending the file.